# hide multiple form fields and preventing white space

Tags: jquery, html

I have a booking form im trying to create, which involves a jquery datepicker and a few dropdown lists. I want to give the user the option of choosing a date from the calendar, then either hide or show several dropdown lists below it based on the DAY they have chosen in the calendar. Each of the dropdown lists are presented one after the other, but are all hidden until the user makes a selection in the datepicker. There is one dropdown list for each day, with different options.

I can get the form to show / hide each dropdown list based on the users selection in the datepicker, but the problem I have is with each different choice, the corresponding dropdown box shuffles down the page, based on where the actual dropdown list sits.

How do I make it so that no mater what dropdown list is shown, it is always displayed on the same row? if that makes sense?

HTML Form:

```
             <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
             <div class="hide" id="hide1">
      <div class="input select">
              <select name="select1" id="Monday">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">(Monday)</option>
              <option value="2">10am - 12pm</option>
              <option value="3">1pm - 3pm</option>
              </select>
            </div></div>
            <br />
            <div class="hide" id="hide2">
      <div class="input select">
              <select name="select2" id="Tuesday">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">(Tuesday)</option>
              <option value="2">10am - 3pm</option>
              <option value="3">7:30pm - 10pm</option>
              </select>
            </div></div>
            <br />
            <div class="hide" id="hide3">
      <div class="input select">
              <select name="select3" id="Wednesday">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">(Wednesday)</option>
              <option value="2">10am - 3pm</option>
              </select>
            </div></div>
            <br />
            <div class="hide" id="hide4">
      <div class="input select">
              <select name="select4" id="Thursday">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">(Thursday)</option>
              <option value="2">10am - 3pm</option>
              </select>
            </div></div>
            <br />
           <div class="hide" id="hide5">
      <div class="input select">
              <select name="select5" id="Friday">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">(Friday)</option>
              <option value="2">1pm - 3pm</option>
              <option value="3">4pm - 6pm</option>
              <option value="4">7:30pm - 10pm</option>
              </select>
            </div></div>
            <br />
            <div class="hide" id="hide6">
      <div class="input select">
              <select name="select6" id="Saturday">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">(Saturday)</option>
              <option value="3">1:30pm - 3:30pm</option>
              <option value="4">8pm - 10pm</option>
              </select>
            </div></div>
            <div class="hide" id="hide7">
      <div class="input select">
              <select name="select7" id="Sunday">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">(Sunday)</option>
              <option value="2">10am - 12pm</option>
              <option value="3">1:30pm - 3:30pm</option>
              </select>
            </div></div>
```

jquery function to hide / show the dropdown lists

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").change(function(){

    if ($(this).val() == "Monday" ) {

        $("#hide1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect


    } else {


        $("#hide1").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } 

    if ($(this).val() == "Tuesday" ) {

        $("#hide2").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect


    } else {


        $("#hide2").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } 

    if ($(this).val() == "Wednesday" ) {

        $("#hide3").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect


    } else {


        $("#hide3").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } 

    if ($(this).val() == "Thursday" ) {

        $("#hide4").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect


    } else {


        $("#hide4").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } 

            if ($(this).val() == "Friday" ) {

        $("#hide5").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect


    } else {


        $("#hide5").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } 

            if ($(this).val() == "Saturday" ) {

        $("#hide6").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect


    } else {


        $("#hide6").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } 

            if ($(this).val() == "Sunday" ) {

        $("#hide7").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect


    } else {


        $("#hide7").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } 

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are having trouble with.  Anyway, I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AXWD5/4/) with your html & js.  I removed the br html tags and added the hide css class definition.

```
 .hide { display: none;}
```

The dropdowns all appear on the row just beneath the datepicker input.

But, like I said, not entirely sure of your goal here :-)

HTH.

Comment: Glad to help.  Can you accept this answer if you are happy to?

Comment: My original question is resolved, but not sure if you would now know how to prevent my hidden fields from being sent when I submit the form? I only want the fields that are visible to be posted when the user presses submit.

Comment: If you disable a field, it will not be sent in a submit - I updated the jsfiddle in the answer to do this.

Comment: Hey Andrew. Can you open another question and ill answer there? This one is getting a little long to be honest. Can we mark this one as resolved as I think the initial question is answered? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I had some issues posting in this one so I did that already :)

Comment: Great. I'll take a look. Again, can you mark this as resolved? You'll get more ppl helping if they see you doing so to your questions :)